# Ethernet not working on RaspberryPi4

Tags: pi-4, sd-card, ethernet

So the Ethernet port on my Raspberry Pi 4 isn't working. No lights coming on, not even a flicker during boot.The power lights come on, and it boots fine, but no Ethernet. ifconfig gives me this:

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether dc:a6:32:9e:d0:be txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
    TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

Loopback and wifi work fine.I can switch it out with a different rpi4 using the same power cable and same Ethernet cable and even using the same SD card with same OS and I get lights and connection. I'm trying to build a cluster, so I've been messing with static addresses across multiple routers and switches. But nothing I try gets this Ethernet port to light up until I switch the board out. Any ideas?

Comment: You might start by listing some real data. You have told us things don't work and claimed to have done questionable things like static addressing but ABSOLUTELY nothing about what YOU have actually done. You might start by tagging with OS.

Comment: I'd start by putting a fresh standard image on the SD card and see if wired Ethernet works then.

Comment: I'd start be ensuring that you've got green lights on both ends of the cable.